# \n is not substituted using strtok

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

I am trying to use the C's strtok function in order to process a char* and print it in a display, and looks like that for some reason I don't know the character '\n' is not substituted by '\0' as I believe strtok does. The code is as follows:

-Declaration of char* and pass to the function where it will be processed:

```
char *string_to_write = "Some text\nSome other text\nNewtext";
malloc(sizeof string_to_write);
screen_write(string_to_write,ALIGN_LEFT_TOP,I2C0);
```

-Processing of char* in function:

```
void screen_write(char *string_to_write,short alignment,short I2C)
{
    char *stw;
    stw = string_to_write;
    char* text_to_send;
    text_to_send=strtok(stw,"\n");
    while(text_to_send != NULL)
    {
        write_text(text_to_send,I2C);
        text_to_send=strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}
```

When applying the code, the result can be seen in [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuf4O.jpg) (Sorry, I am having problems with format adding the image here in the post), where it can be seen that the \n is not substituted as it is the strange character appearing in the image, and the debugger still showed the character as well. Any hints of where can the problem be?

Thanks for your help,
Javier

Comment: `sizeof` does not work for a pointer. Use `strlen() + 1`.

Comment: You cannot `strtok` a string literal. You do not seem to save the return value of `malloc` anywhere.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala In fairness, `sizeof` *does* work on an array…OP just hasn't made an array here (like I'm guessing they wanted to).

Comment: What is the idea of calling `malloc(sizeof string_to_write);` without using its result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` expects to be able to mutate the string you pass it: instead of allocating new memory for each token, it puts `\0` characters into the string at token boundaries, then returns a series of pointers into that string.

But in this case, your string is immutable: it's a constant stored in your program, and can't be changed. So `strtok` is doing its best: it's returning indices into the string for each token's starting point, but it can't insert the `\0`s to mark the ends. Your device can't handle `\n`s in the way you'd expect, so it displays them with that error character instead. (Which is presumably why you're using this code in the first place.)

The key is to pass in only mutable strings. To define a mutable string with a literal value, you need `char my_string[] = "...";` rather than `char* my_string = "..."`. In the latter case, it just gives you a pointer to some constant memory; in the former case, it actually makes an array for you to use. Alternately, you can use `strlen` to find out how long the string is, `malloc` some memory for it, then `strcpy` it over.

P.S. I'm concerned by your `malloc`: you're not saving the memory it gives you anywhere, and you're not doing anything with it. Be sure you know what you're doing before working with dynamic memory allocation! C is not friendly about that, and it's easy to start leaking without realizing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Draconis for your answer, it worked! Indeed for the display font chip \n is somehow understood as the character shown, and also I want to play with it in terms of positioning in the display, that's why I thought of using strtok. One more question, is there any useful link you know for pointers and examples? It is something I really need to work with.

Comment: @Javier I'm afraid I don't know of one; I learned pointers in some CS class years ago. But "how can I learn more about pointers in C" seems like a perfectly valid question to ask on this site!

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I also learned about pointers at university, but it already passed some time since then haha

Answer (score 0):

1.

`malloc(sizeof string_to_write);` - it allocates the `sizeof(char *)` bytes not as many bytes as your string needs. You also do not assign the allocated block to anything

2.

```
char *string_to_write = "Some text\nSome other text\nNewtext";
char *ptr;
ptr = malloc(strlen(string_to_write) + 1);
strcpy(ptr, string_to_write);
screen_write(ptr,ALIGN_LEFT_TOP,I2C0);
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but you might want to explain why exactly you need a mutable string for `strtok`. (And maybe mention `free`, since I'm guessing OP is new to manual memory management.)